# redirect input from keypad/mouse to shell dialog curses gui

Tags: linux, shell-script, dialog

I have been trying to use the "dialog" utility to build interactive menus.
All works fine if I work from a terminal; menus are displayed and I can interact from those menus using my keyboard.

But now I want another device to be the destination for the output and another device (keypad/pointer) to provide input for the dialog.

From my existing TTY (/dev/console) I run dialog and I redirect output to /dev/tty0. The menu appears on tty0 fine; but I expected now to be driving the input from the terminal where I started the dialog script. This does not appear to work.

So can I make sure my existing TTY provides the input to dialog and then how can I inject events into dialog from a device that is not a TTY device. Can I just echo charater sequences somehow into dialog or is the issue it wants a real device that behaves like a TTY inclusing all TTY ioctls?

Simple redirection for the input does not appear to work?

Comment: Is this something I will have to do using a pseudo terminal?
Or can I achieve this with just scripting?

Comment: I just tried some pty code to wrap my dialog script....

Answer (score 0):

My `dialog` command takes a `--input-fd` option to say where to read from. For example, in one terminal type `tty` to find it is using, say, `/dev/pts/4`, then set it so nothing is doing any reads:

```
stty -icanon && sleep 1000
```

In another terminal launch

```
dialog --yesno 'shall we answer yes?' 0 0 --input-fd 3 3</dev/pts/4
```

then anything typed in the first terminal affects the dialog.
Interrupt the sleep and type `stty icanon` to restore the first terminal.

Comment: Driving from one pty I seem to be able to tab between fields on the other pty; but as soon as I try and send key up / key down / space this does not work.

Comment: I thought you were connecting a device directly as input, not passing by another terminal? It was only an example demo. You might try `stty raw` to get the characters through unchanged in this example, but then you will not be able to interrupt the sleep. You can restore with an `stty sane -F /dev/pts/4` given in a different terminal.